# Showing files in kmail

Tags: kubuntu, imap, kmail

Hi
    I added my IMAP mailbox in kmail, but I see that it show me all the files on the remote home directory where the IMAP server is stored. 
Is it possible to show only folders cointaing mails? I tried to play with namespaces but didn't get what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use dimap and I'm therefore not sure whether this works with imap as well:

In your folder list you right-click on an email-account and you can subsribe to the serverside folders you want by simply ticking them. This can be done within the options for each account via your preferences menue also.

Hope this helps. piedro

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use dimap (distributed imap) instead of imap in the account configuration. I believe you can do what you ask for in dimap.